# Screen Blocking Code Required for Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Any good suggestions for a screen blocker when I want my AJAX call to be synchronous (thereby dissalowing a user to do anything until it is finished?)

Comment: Why not use a modal dialog?

Comment: Just use a synchrononous "A"jax, and everything will be locked :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you use Synchronous-JAX (SJAX), you lose the benefits of AJAX, which in most (or all) cases results in bad user experience.

Instead:

- Try using a [modal window](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) to shadow the other parts of the page while your UI of concern is in focus instead of locking the UI using SJAX. Although this is the most straight-forward approach and now is async, you would still lose the entire concept of async if you block the user from doing anything before the server responds.
- A better approach would be to remove temporarily the handling function that calls the AJAX to prevent further action on the form/button/whatever while allowing operations to continue on other parts of the page.

  For example, you have a form. You bind an event handler to that form that calls AJAX on submit. During submit, create some logic that removes that handler temporarily from the form or prevent it from calling AJAX so that further submits do nothing or maybe say "still processing/loading". After the server replies, reattach that handler to make it work.

Comment: good answer and in my opinion the only logical way to answer that :) +1

Comment: the "better approach" is subjective. I want my process to complete before the user does anything else.

Comment: @OliverWatkins you may have that operation block other parts of your page,but not necessarily all. You may want to have some indicator to tell other related parts that this one operation is still processing. For example, GMail. While sending mail, it warns you that you cannot leave if you tried. However, while sending, one can browse through the mail unblocked.